# Efficient read some bytes from DataReader?

Tags: windows-phone-8, datareader, c++-cx

I have a stream with ANSI string. It is prefixed with bytes length. How can I read it into `std::string`?

Something like:

```
short len = reader.readInt16();
char[] result = reader.readBytes(len); // ???
std::string str = std::copy(result, result + len);
```

but there is no method `readBytes(int)`.

Side question: is it slow to read with `readByte()` from `DataReader` one byte at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MSDN, DataReader::ReadBytes exists and is what you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.readbytes

It takes an `Platform::Array<unsigned char>` as an argument, which presumably you'll initialize using the prefixed length, which on returning will contain your bytes.  From there it's a tedious-but-straightforward process to construct the desired `std::string`.

The basic usage will look something like this (apologies, on a Mac at the moment, so precise syntax might be a little off):

```
auto len = reader->ReadInt16();
auto data = ref new Platform::Array<uint8>(len);
reader->ReadBytes(data);

// now data has the bytes you need, and you can make a string with it
```

Note that the above code is *not* production-ready - it's definitely possible that `reader` does not have enough data buffered, and so you'll need to `reader.LoadAsync(len)` and create a continuation to process the data when it is available.  Despite that, hopefully this is enough to get you going.

**EDIT**:

Just noticed your side question.  The short answer is, yes, it is much slower to read a byte at a time, for the reason that it is much more work.

The long answer:  Consider what goes in to each byte:

1. A function call happens - stack frame allocation
2. Some logic of reading a byte from the buffer happens
3. The function returns - stack frame is popped, result is pushed, control returns
4. You take the byte, and push it into a `std::string`, occasionally causing dynamic re-allocation (unless you've already `str.resize(len)`, that is)

Of all the things that happen, the dynamic reallocation is the really performance killer.  That being said, if you have lots of bytes the work of function-calling will dominate the work of reading a byte.

Now, consider what happens when you read all the bytes at once:

1. A function call happens - stack frame, push the result array
2. (in the happy path where all requested data is there) memcpy from the internal buffer to your pre-allocated array
3. return
4. memcpy into the string

This is of course quite a bit faster - your allocations are constant with respect to the number of bytes read, as are the number of function calls.